# How to optimize performance of Results change listeners in Realm (Swift) with a deep hierarchy?

Tags: ios, swift, realm

We're using `Realm` (Swift binding currently in version `3.12.0`) from the earliest days in our project. In some early versions before `1.0` `Realm` provided change listeners for `Results` without actually giving changeSets.
We used this a lot in order to find out if a specific `Results` list changed.

Later the guys at `Realm` exchanged this API with changeSet providing methods. We had to switch and are now mistreating this API just in order to find out if anything in a specific List changed (inserts, deletions, modifications).

Together with `RxSwift` we wrote our own implementation of `Results` change listening which looks like this:

```swift
public var observable: Observable<Base> {
    return Observable.create { observer in
        let token = self.base.observe { changes in
            if case .update = changes {
                observer.onNext(self.base)
            }
        }

        observer.onNext(self.base)

        return Disposables.create(with: {
            observer.onCompleted()
            token.invalidate()
        })
    }
}
```

When we now want to have consecutive updates on a list we subscribe like so:

```swift
someRealm.objects(SomeObject.self).filter(<some filter>).rx.observable
    .subscribe(<subscription code that gets called on every update>)
    //dispose code missing
```

We wrote the extension on `RealmCollection` so that we can subscribe to `List` type as well.

The concept is equal to `RxRealm`'s approach.

So now in our App we have a lot of filtered lists/results that we are subscribing to.

When data gets more and more we notice significant performance losses when it comes to seeing a change visually after writing something into the DB.

For example:
Let's say we have a `Car` Realm Object class with some properties and some 1-to-n and some 1-to-1 relationships. One of the properties is a `Bool`, namely `isDriving`.
Now we have a lot of cars stored in the DB and bunch of change listeners with different filters listing to changes of the cars collection (collection observers listening for changeSets in order to find out if the list was changed).
If I take one car of some list and set the property of `isDriving` from `false` to `true` (important: **we do writes in the background**) ideally the change listener fires fast and I have the nearly immediate correct response to my write **on the main thread**.

**Added with edit on 2019-06-19:**

---

Let's make the scenario still a little more real:
Let's change something down the hierarchy, let's say the tires manufacturer's name. Let's say a `Car` has a `List<Tire>`, a `Tire` has a `Manufacturer` and a `Manufacturer has a`name`. 
Now we're still listing to`Results`collection changes with some more or less complex filters applied.
Then we're changing the name of a`Manufacturer` which is connected to one of the tires which are connected to one of the cars which is in that filtered list.
**Can this still be fast?**

---

Obviously when the length of results/lists where change listeners are attached to gets longer `Realm`'s internal change listener takes longer to calculate the differences and fires later.
So after a write we see the changes - in worst case - much later.

In our case this is not acceptable. So we are thinking through different scenarios.
One scenario would be to not use `.observe` on lists/results anymore and switch to `Realm.observe` which fires every time anything did change in the realm, which is not ideal, but it is fast because the change calculation process is skipped.

**My question is: What can I do to solve this whole dilemma and make our app fast again?**

The crucial thing is the threading stuff. We're always writing in the background due to our design. So the writes itself should be very fast, but then that stuff needs to synchronize to the other threads where Realms are open.
In my understanding that happens after the change detection for all Results has run through, is that right?
So when I read on another thread, the data is only fresh after the thread sync, which happens after all notifications were sent out. But I am not sure currently if the sync happens before, that would be more awesome, did not test it by now.

Comment: Good job on providing a lot of details. When you say you have a lot of cars and a bunch of listeners, what does that mean. Are you using a Collection observer on all cars or are you assigning an object observer on specific cars? Obviously your no using a Realm observer yet - and I wouldn't recommend that. Also, is this a local realm file? A local server? A query or full sync? Also, why did you write your own Change listening since it's built in? I am asking as we have a significantly large data set (Gb's) and we are not really seeing any kind of performance issues like you're describing.

Comment: @Jay Question is up-to-date with more real world information.

Comment: I took this as a little challenge and created a section in an app we're working on that has similar parameters: A ManufacturerClass with a name property, a TireClass that has name and manufacturer properties and then a CarClass that has a name and a `tireList = List<TireClass>()` We created some loops and build 50 manufacturers,  100 tires and then 1000 cars, each having 4 Tires in their List. We added an observer to *all* of the car Results and then started making changes to manufacturers names. The changes reflected instantaneously with 1000 results. We used a Fully Sync'd realm.

Comment: I am pretty sure we could have expanded our test data set to 10x what we did and would have the same results. If you're not seeing that, I would take a look at your own implementation of Results change listening as the one shown in the Realm Docs [Collection Notifications](https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/#collection-notifications) is working beautifully. Note that we made changes both on the main thread as well as background and with changes to only 1 object to changing all the names in a batch write.

Comment: Our schema is way more complex, though, so I think with more data and more schema complexity the change checking algorithms can take some time